# Draw sloped and above path text between two edge-connected nodes with "circle connection bar option"

Tags: nodes, text, mindmaps, edge

I wish to draw the text "USA" on path_1 using options as it was drawn "USA" in path_2, but draw without using nodes,only using edge in path_1.

[image: Draw above path without use node]

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{accsupp}
    \usetikzlibrary{mindmap}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (energy1) at (30:10cm){Text};
    \node (energy2) at (90:10cm) {Text};
    %path_1    \draw [circle connection bar]
    (energy1) edge (energy2) %draw above USA this path without using     node;

%path_2  \draw (energy1)--node[orange,sloped,above=0.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm]{USA}(energy2); 
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use the word `node` for some reasons, you can as well use the `quotes` library:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{accsupp}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,quotes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (energy1) at (30:10cm){Text};
\node (energy2) at (90:10cm) {Text};
%path_1
\draw[circle connection bar]
  (energy1)
  edge["USA" {orange ,sloped,above=.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm}]
  (energy2)
  ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{accsupp}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (energy1) at (30:10cm){};
\node (energy2) at (90:10cm) {};
\draw [circle connection bar]
(energy1) edge node[orange,sloped,above=0.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm]{USA}
(energy2); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]