# Changing the position of the searchable word when using package accsupp

Tags: positioning, accsupp, quotation, search

I used the answer of [my question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/481371/solve-search-for-rotated-or-tilted-words-within-the-zathura-pdf-viewer?noredirect=1#comment1216595_481371) when using package accsupp so that the text can be found in Zathura pdf viewer when leaning over the "circle connection bar". And also I tried to save code using the answer from m[y question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/481415/draw-sloped-and-above-path-text-between-two-edge-connected-nodes-with-circle-co/481420#481420) to use only edge (as answered by @Skillmon). But the searchable word changes position as the relative position of the nodes is changed. See the code examples below. The images match the result of the completed search, so the blue rectangles.

Case 1:

[image: Searchable word was found out of the intended place]

Code of the file TeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,accsupp}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,quotes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (energy1) at (30:10cm){motorcycle};
\node (energy2) at (90:10cm) {motorcycle};
\draw [circle connection bar]
    (energy1) edge (energy2)
    ;
    \draw (energy1)--node[orange, sloped,above=0.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm]{\textsc{%
 \BeginAccSupp{method=escape,ActualText=Japan}%
  Japan%
 \EndAccSupp{}}%
}(energy2);
\node (energy1) at (130:5cm){car};
\node (energy2) at (0:5cm) {car};
\draw[circle connection bar]
  (energy1)
  edge["USA" {orange ,sloped,above=.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm}]
  (energy2)
  ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Original image (without doing research in Zathura):

[image: image original for case 1]

Case 2:

Code of the file TeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,accsupp}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,quotes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (energy1) at (30:10cm){motorcycle};
\node (energy2) at (90:10cm) {motorcycle};
\draw [circle connection bar]
    (energy1) edge (energy2)
    ;
    \draw (energy1)--node[orange, sloped,above=0.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm]{\textsc{%
 \BeginAccSupp{method=escape,ActualText=Japan}%
  Japan%
 \EndAccSupp{}}%
}(energy2);
\node (energy1) at (130:5cm){car};
\node (energy2) at (0:5cm) {car};
\draw[circle connection bar]
  (energy1)
  edge["USA" {orange ,sloped,above=.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm}]
  (energy2)
  ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But by changing the position of the nodes, the searchable word is in the correct place:

[image: Searchable word is found in the correct place (on the circle connection bar path)]

Original image (without searching Zathura):

[image: image original for case 2]

Comment: That's not a tex problem but a problem of your viewer. You should make a bug report there.

Comment: Hi @UlrikeFischer, thanks. I posted this problem at https://git.pwmt.org/pwmt/zathura/issues/68. But I'd like to know if there's any way to circumvent this likely "bug" through a package, library, or additional technique to my code.

Comment: No, as it is completly unclear how your viewer places the search result, it is also not really possible to move the text around. You could perhaps find with try and error a better placement by putting an empty accsupp somewhere else, but every change in the code could break it again.

Comment: Hello @UlrikeFischer, I added an answer, although the form of this answer is what I wanted but it opens the door to many inquiries, I would like you to take a look and give me your feedback

Answer (score 1):

I applied the three different path types described in these two questions ([Solve Search in Zathura](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/481371/solve-search-for-rotated-or-tilted-words-within-the-zathura-pdf-viewer?noredirect=1#comment1216595_481371) and [Draw Text Sloped](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/481415/draw-sloped-and-above-path-text-between-two-edge-connected-nodes-with-circle-co/481420#481420)), and I set up this basic structure below:

```
%Country at (variable) degree

\node (energy1) at (0:10cm){some vehicle};
\node (energy2) at (10:10cm) {some vehicle};
\draw [circle connection bar]
(energy1)
  edge["Country" {orange ,sloped,above=.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm}]
  (energy2)
    (energy1) edge node[orange,sloped,above=0.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm]{Country}
(energy2)
(energy1)--node[orange, sloped,above=0.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm]{\textsc{%
 \BeginAccSupp{method=escape,ActualText=Country}%
  usa%
 \EndAccSupp{}}%
}(energy2)
;
```

I planned to repeat this structure for all 10 degree intervals starting from zero degrees to 360 degrees in order to test whether the problem during the search would occur again. To differentiate the word on the path at every 10 degree interval I used [this list of countries](https://www.britannica.com/topic/list-of-countries-1993160) in order to elucidate, starting in Afghanistan (at 0 degree) and going to Chile (at 360 degrees). This results in the resulting complete code and image resulting:

[image: image resulting from the complete code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,accsupp}
\usepackage[paperwidth=30cm,paperheight=30cm,bottom=-15cm,left=2cm]{geometry}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,quotes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

%Afghanistan at 10 degree

\node (energy1) at (0:10cm){some vehicle};
\node (energy2) at (10:10cm) {some vehicle};
\draw [circle connection bar]
(energy1)
  edge["Afghanistan" {orange ,sloped,above=.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm}]
  (energy2)
    (energy1) edge node[orange,sloped,above=0.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm]{Afghanistan}
(energy2)
(energy1)--node[orange, sloped,above=0.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm]{\textsc{%
 \BeginAccSupp{method=escape,ActualText=Afghanistan}%
  usa%
 \EndAccSupp{}}%
}(energy2)
;

%Albania at 20 degree
\node (energy1) at (0:10cm){some vehicle};
\node (energy2) at (20:10cm) {some vehicle};
\draw [circle connection bar]
(energy1)
  edge["Albania" {orange ,sloped,above=.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm}]
  (energy2)
    (energy1) edge node[orange,sloped,above=0.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm]{Albania}
(energy2)
(energy1)--node[orange, sloped,above=0.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm]{\textsc{%
 \BeginAccSupp{method=escape,ActualText=Albania}%
  usa%
 \EndAccSupp{}}%
}(energy2)
;


%Algeria at 30 degree
\node (energy1) at (0:10cm){some vehicle};
\node (energy2) at (30:10cm) {some vehicle};
\draw [circle connection bar]
(energy1)
  edge["Algeria" {orange ,sloped,above=.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm}]
  (energy2)
    (energy1) edge node[orange,sloped,above=0.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm]{Algeria}
(energy2)
(energy1)--node[orange, sloped,above=0.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm]{\textsc{%
 \BeginAccSupp{method=escape,ActualText=Algeria}%
  usa%
 \EndAccSupp{}}%
}(energy2)
;


%Andorra at 40 degree
\node (energy1) at (0:10cm){some vehicle};
\node (energy2) at (40:10cm) {some vehicle};
\draw [circle connection bar]
(energy1)
  edge["Andorra" {orange ,sloped,above=.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm}]
  (energy2)
    (energy1) edge node[orange,sloped,above=0.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm]{Andorra}
(energy2)
(energy1)--node[orange, sloped,above=0.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm]{\textsc{%
 \BeginAccSupp{method=escape,ActualText=Andorra}%
  usa%
 \EndAccSupp{}}%
}(energy2)
;



%Angola at 50 degree
\node (energy1) at (0:10cm){some vehicle};
\node (energy2) at (50:10cm) {some vehicle};
\draw [circle connection bar]
(energy1)
  edge["Angola" {orange ,sloped,above=.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm}]
  (energy2)
    (energy1) edge node[orange,sloped,above=0.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm]{Angola}
(energy2)
(energy1)--node[orange, sloped,above=0.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm]{\textsc{%
 \BeginAccSupp{method=escape,ActualText=Angola}%
  usa%
 \EndAccSupp{}}%
}(energy2)
;



%Antigua and Barbuda at 60 degree
\node (energy1) at (0:10cm){some vehicle};
\node (energy2) at (60:10cm) {some vehicle};
\draw [circle connection bar]
(energy1)
  edge["Antigua and Barbuda" {orange ,sloped,above=.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm}]
  (energy2)
    (energy1) edge node[orange,sloped,above=0.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm]{Antigua and Barbuda}
(energy2)
(energy1)--node[orange, sloped,above=0.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm]{\textsc{%
 \BeginAccSupp{method=escape,ActualText=Antigua and Barbuda}%
  usa%
 \EndAccSupp{}}%
}(energy2)
;


%Argentina at 70 degree
\node (energy1) at (0:10cm){some vehicle};
\node (energy2) at (70:10cm) {some vehicle};
\draw [circle connection bar]
(energy1)
  edge["Argentina" {orange ,sloped,above=.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm}]
  (energy2)
    (energy1) edge node[orange,sloped,above=0.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm]{Argentina}
(energy2)
(energy1)--node[orange, sloped,above=0.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm]{\textsc{%
 \BeginAccSupp{method=escape,ActualText=Argentina}%
  usa%
 \EndAccSupp{}}%
}(energy2)
;



%Armenia at 80 degree
\node (energy1) at (0:10cm){some vehicle};
\node (energy2) at (80:10cm) {some vehicle};
\draw [circle connection bar]
(energy1)
  edge["Armenia" {orange ,sloped,above=.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm}]
  (energy2)
    (energy1) edge node[orange,sloped,above=0.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm]{Armenia}
(energy2)
(energy1)--node[orange, sloped,above=0.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm]{\textsc{%
 \BeginAccSupp{method=escape,ActualText=Armenia}%
  usa%
 \EndAccSupp{}}%
}(energy2)
;


%Australia at 90 degree
\node (energy1) at (0:10cm){some vehicle};
\node (energy2) at (90:10cm) {some vehicle};
\draw [circle connection bar]
(energy1)
  edge["Australia" {orange ,sloped,above=.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm}]
  (energy2)
    (energy1) edge node[orange,sloped,above=0.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm]{Australia}
(energy2)
(energy1)--node[orange, sloped,above=0.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm]{\textsc{%
 \BeginAccSupp{method=escape,ActualText=Australia}%
  usa%
 \EndAccSupp{}}%
}(energy2)
;


%Austria at 100 degree
\node (energy1) at (0:10cm){some vehicle};
\node (energy2) at (100:10cm) {some vehicle};
\draw [circle connection bar]
(energy1)
  edge["Austria" {orange ,sloped,above=.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm}]
  (energy2)
    (energy1) edge node[orange,sloped,above=0.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm]{Austria}
(energy2)
(energy1)--node[orange, sloped,above=0.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm]{\textsc{%
 \BeginAccSupp{method=escape,ActualText=Austria}%
  usa%
 \EndAccSupp{}}%
}(energy2)
;


%Azerbaijan at 110 degree
\node (energy1) at (0:10cm){some vehicle};
\node (energy2) at (110:10cm) {some vehicle};
\draw [circle connection bar]
(energy1)
  edge["Azerbaijan" {orange ,sloped,above=.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm}]
  (energy2)
    (energy1) edge node[orange,sloped,above=0.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm]{Azerbaijan}
(energy2)
(energy1)--node[orange, sloped,above=0.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm]{\textsc{%
 \BeginAccSupp{method=escape,ActualText=Azerbaijan}%
  usa%
 \EndAccSupp{}}%
}(energy2)
;


%The Bahamas at 120 degree
\node (energy1) at (0:10cm){some vehicle};
\node (energy2) at (120:10cm) {some vehicle};
\draw [circle connection bar]
(energy1)
  edge["The Bahamas" {orange ,sloped,above=.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm}]
  (energy2)
    (energy1) edge node[orange,sloped,above=0.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm]{The Bahamas}
(energy2)
(energy1)--node[orange, sloped,above=0.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm]{\textsc{%
 \BeginAccSupp{method=escape,ActualText=The Bahamas}%
  usa%
 \EndAccSupp{}}%
}(energy2)
;



%Bahrain at 130 degree
\node (energy1) at (0:10cm){some vehicle};
\node (energy2) at (130:10cm) {some vehicle};
\draw [circle connection bar]
(energy1)
  edge["Bahrain" {orange ,sloped,above=.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm}]
  (energy2)
    (energy1) edge node[orange,sloped,above=0.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm]{Bahrain}
(energy2)
(energy1)--node[orange, sloped,above=0.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm]{\textsc{%
 \BeginAccSupp{method=escape,ActualText=Bahrain}%
  usa%
 \EndAccSupp{}}%
}(energy2)
;



%Bangladesh at 140 degree
\node (energy1) at (0:10cm){some vehicle};
\node (energy2) at (140:10cm) {some vehicle};
\draw [circle connection bar]
(energy1)
  edge["Bangladesh" {orange ,sloped,above=.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm}]
  (energy2)
    (energy1) edge node[orange,sloped,above=0.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm]{Bangladesh}
(energy2)
(energy1)--node[orange, sloped,above=0.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm]{\textsc{%
 \BeginAccSupp{method=escape,ActualText=Bangladesh}%
  usa%
 \EndAccSupp{}}%
}(energy2)
;


%Barbados at 150 degree
\node (energy1) at (0:10cm){some vehicle};
\node (energy2) at (150:10cm) {some vehicle};
\draw [circle connection bar]
(energy1)
  edge["Barbados" {orange ,sloped,above=.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm}]
  (energy2)
    (energy1) edge node[orange,sloped,above=0.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm]{Barbados}
(energy2)
(energy1)--node[orange, sloped,above=0.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm]{\textsc{%
 \BeginAccSupp{method=escape,ActualText=Barbados}%
  usa%
 \EndAccSupp{}}%
}(energy2)
;



%Belarus at 160 degree
\node (energy1) at (0:10cm){some vehicle};
\node (energy2) at (160:10cm) {some vehicle};
\draw [circle connection bar]
(energy1)
  edge["Belarus" {orange ,sloped,above=.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm}]
  (energy2)
    (energy1) edge node[orange,sloped,above=0.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm]{Belarus}
(energy2)
(energy1)--node[orange, sloped,above=0.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm]{\textsc{%
 \BeginAccSupp{method=escape,ActualText=Belarus}%
  usa%
 \EndAccSupp{}}%
}(energy2)
;



%Belgium at 170 degree
\node (energy1) at (0:10cm){some vehicle};
\node (energy2) at (170:10cm) {some vehicle};
\draw [circle connection bar]
(energy1)
  edge["Belgium" {orange ,sloped,above=.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm}]
  (energy2)
    (energy1) edge node[orange,sloped,above=0.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm]{Belgium}
(energy2)
(energy1)--node[orange, sloped,above=0.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm]{\textsc{%
 \BeginAccSupp{method=escape,ActualText=Belgium}%
  usa%
 \EndAccSupp{}}%
}(energy2)
;


%Belize at 180 degree
\node (energy1) at (0:10cm){some vehicle};
\node (energy2) at (180:10cm) {some vehicle};
\draw [circle connection bar]
(energy1)
  edge["Belize" {orange ,sloped,above=.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm}]
  (energy2)
    (energy1) edge node[orange,sloped,above=0.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm]{Belize}
(energy2)
(energy1)--node[orange, sloped,above=0.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm]{\textsc{%
 \BeginAccSupp{method=escape,ActualText=Belize}%
  usa%
 \EndAccSupp{}}%
}(energy2)
;

%target at +180 degree



%Benin at 190 degree

\node (energy1) at (0:10cm){some vehicle};
\node (energy2) at (190:10cm) {some vehicle};
\draw [circle connection bar]
(energy1)
  edge["Benin" {orange ,sloped,above=.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm}]
  (energy2)
    (energy1) edge node[orange,sloped,above=0.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm]{Benin}
(energy2)
(energy1)--node[orange, sloped,above=0.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm]{\textsc{%
 \BeginAccSupp{method=escape,ActualText=Benin}%
  usa%
 \EndAccSupp{}}%
}(energy2)
;

%Bhutan at 200 degree
\node (energy1) at (0:10cm){some vehicle};
\node (energy2) at (200:10cm) {some vehicle};
\draw [circle connection bar]
(energy1)
  edge["Bhutan" {orange ,sloped,above=.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm}]
  (energy2)
    (energy1) edge node[orange,sloped,above=0.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm]{Bhutan}
(energy2)
(energy1)--node[orange, sloped,above=0.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm]{\textsc{%
 \BeginAccSupp{method=escape,ActualText=Bhutan}%
  usa%
 \EndAccSupp{}}%
}(energy2)
;


%Bolivia at 210 degree
\node (energy1) at (0:10cm){some vehicle};
\node (energy2) at (210:10cm) {some vehicle};
\draw [circle connection bar]
(energy1)
  edge["Bolivia" {orange ,sloped,above=.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm}]
  (energy2)
    (energy1) edge node[orange,sloped,above=0.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm]{Bolivia}
(energy2)
(energy1)--node[orange, sloped,above=0.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm]{\textsc{%
 \BeginAccSupp{method=escape,ActualText=Bolivia}%
  usa%
 \EndAccSupp{}}%
}(energy2)
;


%Bosnia and Herzegovina at 220 degree
\node (energy1) at (0:10cm){some vehicle};
\node (energy2) at (220:10cm) {some vehicle};
\draw [circle connection bar]
(energy1)
  edge["Bosnia and Herzegovina" {orange ,sloped,above=.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm}]
  (energy2)
    (energy1) edge node[orange,sloped,above=0.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm]{Bosnia and Herzegovina}
(energy2)
(energy1)--node[orange, sloped,above=0.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm]{\textsc{%
 \BeginAccSupp{method=escape,ActualText=Bosnia and Herzegovina}%
  usa%
 \EndAccSupp{}}%
}(energy2)
;



%Botswana at 230 degree
\node (energy1) at (0:10cm){some vehicle};
\node (energy2) at (230:10cm) {some vehicle};
\draw [circle connection bar]
(energy1)
  edge["Botswana" {orange ,sloped,above=.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm}]
  (energy2)
    (energy1) edge node[orange,sloped,above=0.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm]{Botswana}
(energy2)
(energy1)--node[orange, sloped,above=0.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm]{\textsc{%
 \BeginAccSupp{method=escape,ActualText=Botswana}%
  usa%
 \EndAccSupp{}}%
}(energy2)
;



%Brazil at 240 degree
\node (energy1) at (0:10cm){some vehicle};
\node (energy2) at (240:10cm) {some vehicle};
\draw [circle connection bar]
(energy1)
  edge["Brazil" {orange ,sloped,above=.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm}]
  (energy2)
    (energy1) edge node[orange,sloped,above=0.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm]{Brazil}
(energy2)
(energy1)--node[orange, sloped,above=0.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm]{\textsc{%
 \BeginAccSupp{method=escape,ActualText=Brazil}%
  usa%
 \EndAccSupp{}}%
}(energy2)
;


%Brunei at 250 degree
\node (energy1) at (0:10cm){some vehicle};
\node (energy2) at (250:10cm) {some vehicle};
\draw [circle connection bar]
(energy1)
  edge["Brunei" {orange ,sloped,above=.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm}]
  (energy2)
    (energy1) edge node[orange,sloped,above=0.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm]{Brunei}
(energy2)
(energy1)--node[orange, sloped,above=0.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm]{\textsc{%
 \BeginAccSupp{method=escape,ActualText=Brunei}%
  usa%
 \EndAccSupp{}}%
}(energy2)
;



%Bulgaria at 260 degree
\node (energy1) at (0:10cm){some vehicle};
\node (energy2) at (260:10cm) {some vehicle};
\draw [circle connection bar]
(energy1)
  edge["Bulgaria" {orange ,sloped,above=.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm}]
  (energy2)
    (energy1) edge node[orange,sloped,above=0.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm]{Bulgaria}
(energy2)
(energy1)--node[orange, sloped,above=0.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm]{\textsc{%
 \BeginAccSupp{method=escape,ActualText=Bulgaria}%
  usa%
 \EndAccSupp{}}%
}(energy2)
;


%Burkina Faso at 270 degree
\node (energy1) at (0:10cm){some vehicle};
\node (energy2) at (270:10cm) {some vehicle};
\draw [circle connection bar]
(energy1)
  edge["Burkina Faso" {orange ,sloped,above=.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm}]
  (energy2)
    (energy1) edge node[orange,sloped,above=0.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm]{Burkina Faso}
(energy2)
(energy1)--node[orange, sloped,above=0.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm]{\textsc{%
 \BeginAccSupp{method=escape,ActualText=Burkina Faso}%
  usa%
 \EndAccSupp{}}%
}(energy2)
;

%Burundi at 280 degree
\node (energy1) at (0:10cm){some vehicle};
\node (energy2) at (280:10cm) {some vehicle};
\draw [circle connection bar]
(energy1)
  edge["Burundi" {orange ,sloped,above=.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm}]
  (energy2)
    (energy1) edge node[orange,sloped,above=0.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm]{Burundi}
(energy2)
(energy1)--node[orange, sloped,above=0.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm]{\textsc{%
 \BeginAccSupp{method=escape,ActualText=Burundi}%
  usa%
 \EndAccSupp{}}%
}(energy2)
;


%Cabo Verde at 290 degree
\node (energy1) at (0:10cm){some vehicle};
\node (energy2) at (290:10cm) {some vehicle};
\draw [circle connection bar]
(energy1)
  edge["Cabo Verde" {orange ,sloped,above=.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm}]
  (energy2)
    (energy1) edge node[orange,sloped,above=0.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm]{Cabo Verde}
(energy2)
(energy1)--node[orange, sloped,above=0.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm]{\textsc{%
 \BeginAccSupp{method=escape,ActualText=Cabo Verde}%
  usa%
 \EndAccSupp{}}%
}(energy2)
;



%Cambodia at 310 degree
\node (energy1) at (0:10cm){some vehicle};
\node (energy2) at (310:10cm) {some vehicle};
\draw [circle connection bar]
(energy1)
  edge["Cambodia" {orange ,sloped,above=.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm}]
  (energy2)
    (energy1) edge node[orange,sloped,above=0.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm]{Cambodia}
(energy2)
(energy1)--node[orange, sloped,above=0.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm]{\textsc{%
 \BeginAccSupp{method=escape,ActualText=Cambodia}%
  usa%
 \EndAccSupp{}}%
}(energy2)
;



%Cameroon at 320 degree
\node (energy1) at (0:10cm){some vehicle};
\node (energy2) at (320:10cm) {some vehicle};
\draw [circle connection bar]
(energy1)
  edge["Cameroon" {orange ,sloped,above=.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm}]
  (energy2)
    (energy1) edge node[orange,sloped,above=0.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm]{Cameroon}
(energy2)
(energy1)--node[orange, sloped,above=0.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm]{\textsc{%
 \BeginAccSupp{method=escape,ActualText=Cameroon}%
  usa%
 \EndAccSupp{}}%
}(energy2)
;


%Canada at 330 degree
\node (energy1) at (0:10cm){some vehicle};
\node (energy2) at (330:10cm) {some vehicle};
\draw [circle connection bar]
(energy1)
  edge["Canada" {orange ,sloped,above=.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm}]
  (energy2)
    (energy1) edge node[orange,sloped,above=0.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm]{Canada}
(energy2)
(energy1)--node[orange, sloped,above=0.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm]{\textsc{%
 \BeginAccSupp{method=escape,ActualText=Canada}%
  usa%
 \EndAccSupp{}}%
}(energy2)
;



%Central African Republic at 340 degree
\node (energy1) at (0:10cm){some vehicle};
\node (energy2) at (340:10cm) {some vehicle};
\draw [circle connection bar]
(energy1)
  edge["Central African Republic" {orange ,sloped,above=.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm}]
  (energy2)
    (energy1) edge node[orange,sloped,above=0.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm]{Central African Republic}
(energy2)
(energy1)--node[orange, sloped,above=0.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm]{\textsc{%
 \BeginAccSupp{method=escape,ActualText=Central African Republic}%
  usa%
 \EndAccSupp{}}%
}(energy2)
;

%Chad at 350 degree
\node (energy1) at (0:10cm){some vehicle};
\node (energy2) at (350:10cm) {some vehicle};
\draw [circle connection bar]
(energy1)
  edge["Chad" {orange ,sloped,above=.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm}]
  (energy2)
    (energy1) edge node[orange,sloped,above=0.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm]{Chad}
(energy2)
(energy1)--node[orange, sloped,above=0.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm]{\textsc{%
 \BeginAccSupp{method=escape,ActualText=Chad}%
  usa%
 \EndAccSupp{}}%
}(energy2)
;


%Chile at 360 degree
\node (energy1) at (0:10cm){some vehicle};
\node (energy2) at (360:10cm) {some vehicle};
\draw [circle connection bar]
(energy1)
  edge["Chile" {orange ,sloped,above=.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm}]
  (energy2)
    (energy1) edge node[orange,sloped,above=0.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm]{Chile}
(energy2)
(energy1)--node[orange, sloped,above=0.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm]{\textsc{%
 \BeginAccSupp{method=escape,ActualText=Chile}%
  usa%
 \EndAccSupp{}}%
}(energy2)
;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I did several searches for words (countries) where the path was with different inclination, and even opposed, and I no longer encountered the problem of the text being sought to be moved from the correct position.
Note: Correct position is on the path as expected by the commands: above = 0.5 and align = center.
I conclude two things about this:

First - It is a solution because I did not specify or limit how to solve it when I asked my question.

Second - Not an economic solution in a code, but a palliative (if you want to understand as improvisation too).

In addition, there is still a need to make it more nimble (delimit) to where this problem is a bug of Zathura ([I have already questioned the responsible staff](https://git.pwmt.org/pwmt/zathura/issues/68)) and to what extent there may be a method not yet discussed about the reason for using the basic structure as described at the beginning have worked. I tried to use the three basic structure commands in isolation, and I could not solve the search problem, it was just using the three commands together that it was possible to no longer get the Zathura search problem.

So I appreciate new answers or comments that might better clarify what is possible to be perfected in using the TeX language to get another alternative solution that will work around this problem with Zathura. And also determine why it worked to use three commands as described in the basic structure, because I just could not understand why it worked.

Note: I was wondering if I should put this answer within my question or should I use this answer to answer my question, but considering the ambiguities present in my explanation in this answer I expect to be following the rules.